# ¿Cómo puedo hacer operaciones entre columnas (creando nuevas con su resultado) de una data importada desde excel a rstudio?

Tags: importación

He importado datos desde un archivo excel a rstudio, ahora necesito comenzar a hacer operaciones entre las columnas que contienen esos datos importados, la cuestión es que no sé cómo hacerlo, crear nuevas columnas con nuevos datos a partir de operaciones entre las columnas ya existentes.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.